# Password protect a single page

Tags: security, password, singles

Is it possible to password protect a single page in Craft? Wordpress has this functionality built in. I would love to do it in Craft as well.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Use the [RequireLogin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/requirelogin) tag at the top of a page:

```
{% requireLogin %}
```

> This tag will ensure that the user is logged in. If they aren’t, they will be redirected to the Login page, and returned to the original page after successfully logging in.

(make sure you are logged out before you test this!)